# mapping Embedded List from single element with mapstruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

I worked with mappstruct, and I have an issue, I don't know if mapstruct can help with it
The probleme is I have a DATA class

```
public class Data {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String state;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private String zipCode;
}
```

and  Address

```
Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String state;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private String zipCode;
```

and Person

````
@Data
public class Person {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private List<Address> list;
}```

So the person have a list of address and I want from One Data object create one adresse Object 
and add that object to Person  
So after the mapping I need to have Person with List(size == 1) of address 

the mapper
````

@Mapper
public interface DataToPerson {

```
DataToPerson MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(DataToPerson.class);

Person dataToPerson(Data data);
```

}

```
 is that possible ? 

Thank you so much
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to perform such a mapping you need to tell MapStruct how to map into the `List<Address>`.

e.g.

```
@Mapper
public interface DataToPerson {

    DataToPerson MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(DataToPerson.class);

    @Mapping(target = "list", source = "data")
    Person dataToPerson(Data data);

    default List<Address> dataToAddressList(Data data) {
        return data != null ? Collections.singletonList(dataToAddress(data)) : null;
    }

    Address dataToAddress(Data data);

}
```